# Moment get next date in arrays of dates

Tags: node.js, momentjs

I have an array of dates in the format of `March 1st` or `May 2nd` and I want to use moment.js to iterate through those dates and figure out which one is closest to the current day in nodejs.

Comment: The format doesn't provide enough information to find the closest date to the current date. We also need information about the year. Can you give more information about that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must cycle every element in the array, and calculate the absolute difference (with `Math.abs()`) between the date of array element and now (`moment()`).
You must specify the format of array elements, in this case the moment format is `MMMM Do`.

```
const arr = ['March 1st', 'April 1st', 'April 28th', 'May 1st', 'May 2nd', 'September 26th'];

let lastDiff;
let nearest;

for (const date of arr) {
  const diff = Math.abs(moment(date, 'MMMM Do').diff(moment(), 'days'));

  if (lastDiff === undefined || lastDiff > diff) {
    lastDiff = diff;
    nearest = date;
  }
}

console.log(nearest)
console.log(moment(nearest, 'MMMM Do').format())
```

This method considers that year is the same of now.

Answer (score 1):

We can use Array.reduce to find the nearest date to the current day. We parse each date to get a moment instance, then get the absolute offset from the current date. If this is lower than the nearest value, we replace it.

```js
const dates = ["January 1st", "March 28th", "April 12th", "April 25th", "May 2nd", "September 8th"];

const now = moment();
const nearestDate = dates.reduce((nearest, dateStr) => {
    const momentDate = moment(dateStr, "MMMM D");
    const timeFromNow = Math.abs(momentDate - now);
    const nearestTimeFromNow = Math.abs(nearest - now);
    
    if (!nearestTimeFromNow || timeFromNow < nearestTimeFromNow) { 
        nearest = momentDate;
    }
    
    return nearest;
})

console.log("Nearest date to now:", nearestDate.format("MMMM Do"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```